# How to get raw code from a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

It would be really handy to have a button to copy raw code from a Jupyter notebook to the clipboard so it can be dumped into a text file, .py/.R script, or straight into the terminal (a button like github has to copy to clipboard)

Does a button (or even a chrome add on) exist?

Obviously you could copy/paste sections manually into a txt file, but that's laborious for long notebooks/markdowns

Comment: How about file > download?

Comment: try `import nbformat.v4` its the library of jupyter, i did similar stuff some time ago [here](https://github.com/rhoit/pyorg2ipynb) it won't be hard to filp it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,there is a button:

File > Download as > Python (.py)

Answer (score 1):

There is a more handy way for Mac OS users.

By installing an Automator script converting the `ipynb` file to `py` first, then automatically copy the content to the clipboard with one right-click and select the script in the Quick Action part.

[Github link](https://github.com/JunsW/FastJN)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the magic command %%writefile to save as py file

```
%%writefile "directory/to/file/filename.py"
```

However, you should place this command at the top of the cell, otherwise it will throw an error.